# When we should use SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Let's say I have a function template, that inside the code uses for example `+` operator and it copies the element passed as parameter:

```
template<class T>
T calcDouble(T&& el){
   return el + el;
}
```

Should I use SFINAE to limit `T` to be copy constructable and have `operator+` defined if I have no other variant of that?
In other words, should I use SFINAE to define what that type should have if there is no intent to make an "overloading" of that template that uses other things to achieve what we want? (for example using `*2` and so require that has `operator-` and is castable to `int`)

Comment: This would be entirely your own decision to make.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what i want to know if anything changes? idk, like if the compiler errors are more readable or something like this

Comment: This is kind of opinion-based. If you ask me, it's not worth it at all to obscure the code. SFINAE is objectively ugly ;) Use C++20 concepts if you have them.

Comment: SFINAE is a mechanism that drives overload resolution. Do you have another overload? If not, there is no point to go down that route.

Comment: Sometimes SFINAE is very important, for example in converting constructors like in `template<class U> unique_ptr::unique_ptr(U p);`, in order to prevent it from interfering with other overloads.

Comment: @rustyx yes sure, for example to have different behavior for T and T[], but what about there is no overloading to do?

Comment: Although I would agree that SFINAE usually results in somewhat improved error messages the improvement is rarely dramatic.  The major change will be where the initial error occurs since SFINAE, by definition, changes where the error occurs. It is arguable how much better seven onion layers of cryptic error messages is, instead of eight.

Comment: This is really asking for opinion... my opinion: keep it simple and don't use SFINAE if no overloading is involved.